# Creating a chart in Excel, with sparse and different timelines in C#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, charts, timeline

I'm trying to create charts in Excel.
The series(es) have different and sparse timeline.

Eg, let's say I measure temperature for different sensors/devices.

For device #1, I can have this data:

(indicating the time of measurement, and value)

1. 9:30:12 = -100
2. 9:45:17 = -90

and for device #2:

1. 9:33:12 = -80
2. 9:47:17 = -50

As you can see, the times are sparse/scattered.

My problem is that when I try to add these values as **DateTime**, on **XValues**,
the chart wrongly aligns all series to the same start time.

See attached image.

I've managed to do some temporary bypass, if instead of **DateTime** for **XValues**,
I use **int** of "milli-seconds-from-midnight",
as you can see in the attached image.

Then the line is drawn correctly, but it's hard to understand the scale/labels, and I want to fix it and show it as time/dates.

In the code, for chart type I use:

```
XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines
```

and for the values I uses:

```
newSeries.Values = values.ToArray();
newSeries.XValues = dates.ToArray();
```

Any idea how to fix it to work correctly with **DateTime** ?

Thanks for any help,
Si.

[image]

Comment: which library do you use to create chart?

Comment: Im using the buitin chart of excel